# Own partition for database data

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I don't know you but I, I have lost DB data several times when I decide reinstall an OS...
Yes, I know... please don't say it.

So is not first time that I think in give his own partition to the DB data (/var/lib/mysql). Indeed I did it one time, but now I don't remember why, did not worked as expected. 
Reinstall WP, Joomla, download customer data is not so fun.

Any idea to solve this painful issue?

THX.-

Comment: You may get a better response if asked on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: You have bigger problems than that: hardware failures, attacks, accidental deletions... Reinstalling the O.S. is most likely something you do on purpose so there's a chance that you can prevent it. What do you have against backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to backup before re-installing the OS with mysqldump and then import it back.

That said, putting MySQL data on a separate partition is a good idea. For that first you need to make a a partition for it. Once you have a partition and it's mounted you can copy /var/lib/mysql/* to it

```
cp /var/lib/mysql/* /new/partition/mysql/
```

Now edit your my.cnf to point to a different data directory

```
datadir         = /new/partition/mysql
```

Make sure your permissions are correct and restart MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I'll try it in that way. Maybe the permissions is the key.

Comment: Also, if you are running linux with apparmor or selinux you may have to make changes to the security rules as well.

Comment: Absolutely right! apparmor is a "must to check". Thanks. All running as silk now.

Answer (score 1):

Any server should have an complete backup-script that saves all needed data to reinstall your server. Not specially for reinstall, but for the case of emergency, that your harddrive fails.

If you have an complete backup-script, you can use that also for an complete backup before you reinstall your server.

Edit: The same for your client btw - don't wait for your first hdd-crash to learn it the hard way...

Comment: Backups. Yes, that thing... :)